# Showing that a function is constant on a disc D

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations, radial-basis-functions

Recall that a function $f(z)$ is called radial if it is constant along the circles of center $0$. Let $f$ be a radial holomorphic function defined on the unit disc $D$.

Show that $f$ is constant. (Hint: apply the
Cauchy-Riemann equations)

I've come across this problem but I've never heard of radial functions.

I know that if $f$ is holomorphic then it is complex differentiable and so $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x} $ and $\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}$ both exist. And so we have the Cauchy-Riemann equations that hold.

But how do I use these facts (that $f$ is radial and holomorphic) to prove that it's constant ?

Please I need help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cauchy Riemann equations in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ [ Ref: [Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245754/cauchy-riemann-equations-in-polar-form) ]

Since the real and imaginary parts depend only on $r$ and not on $\theta$ the partial derivatives of $u =\Re f$ and $v =\Im f$ w.r.t. $\theta$ are $0$. But Cauchy Riemann equations now show that the partial derivatives w.r.t. $r$ are also $0$ forcing these functions to be constants.

Comment: What do you mean by "the real and imaginary parts depend only on r and not on θ the partial derivatives of u=Rf and v=If w.r.t. θ are 0". How do the real and imaginary parts depend on r only?

Comment: The hypothesis is $f(z)=f(|z|)$ for all $z$. [ Note that $z$ and $|z|$ lie on the same circle centered at the origin]. Hence $f(re^{i\theta})=f(r)$ which does not depend on $\theta$.