# Check the continuity and analyticity of complex function $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Given function $$\displaystyle f(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\bar{ z}^2}{z} & \text{if} \;\; z \neq 0\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have to  check its continuity and analyticity.

**solution i tried**- i write the function as $$f(z)=\displaystyle  \frac{r^2e^{-2i\theta}} 
{re^{i\theta}}$$

$$\lim_{r \to 0}f(z)=re^{-3i\theta}\to 0$$

so this is continuous on whole $\mathbb{C}$

For analyticity i solved this as $$\frac{(x-iy)^2}{(x+iy)}=\frac{x^2-y^2-2xiy}{x+iy}$$

after solving this i get $$u=\frac{x^3-xy^2-2xy^2}{x^2+y^2} ,\;\;v=\frac{-2x^2y-x^2y+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

now i have to fin the $u_x$ and $v_x$ $u_y$ and $v_y$ ,after doing this it seems very complicated to solve further ,can someone please provide a short method to solve this question,or is there any other method which can make it simple and more understandable.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Hint: This is easy if you C-R equatins in polar form: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245754/cauchy-riemann-equations-in-polar-form

Comment: Wirtinger derivatives might come in handy here too.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg how Wirtinger derivatives will help here ,can you please elaborate this.

Comment: @TheStudent: See answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that $f$ is continuous for $z \neq 0$ and since $|f(z)| \le |z|$ it is continuous at $z=0$.

Suppose $f$ is analytic, then $g(z) = z^3f(z) = |z|^2 $ would be analytic, but since $g$ is real valued it must be a constant hence a contradiction. Hence $f$ is not analytic.

Comment: but how  $|f(z)| \leq |z|$?

Comment: If $z\neq 0$ then $|f(z)| = { |z|^2 \over |z|} = |z|$.

Comment: but in question it is $\displaystyle |f(z)|=\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}$

Comment: $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{x^2+(-y)^2} =  |\bar{z}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$. Among their basic properties is that they satisfy the product and quotient rule, further $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \bar z= 1$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} z=0$, meaning that when applying $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ to an algebraic expression in $z$ and $\bar z$, you can treat $z$ as a constant and $\bar z$ as a variable like in old school calculus. Consequently:

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\bar z^2}{z} = 2 \frac{\bar z}{z} \qquad (*)$$

However, another basic use of the Wirtinger derivatives is that a function $f$ is holomorphic in an open set if and only if $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} f=0$ in that set (since this condition actually encodes the Cauchy-Riemann equations). So $(*)$ shows that your $f$ is not holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, hence not analytic.

Comment: I have never seen Wirtinger derivatives used in single variable complex analysis.

Comment: @copper.hat Really? I saw them pretty early in the one function theory class I took (which was entirely about single variables) and have found them useful sometimes. They are tailor-made for examples like this.

Comment: Might be generational, my last complex analysis class was in the mid 80's. The first time I encountered them was on MSE about 2 years ago. My exposure to complex analysis is mainly through control systems.